# MongoDB transform [{k1:v1},{k2:v2}] into {v1: v2}

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with the following schema:

```
// ----- SOURCE SCHEMA ----- //

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5564e8937c32c85f03ea028a"),
    "sku" : "MD01"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5564e8c97c32c85f03ea028b"),
    "sku" : "MD02"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5564e8dd7c32c85f03ea028c"),
    "sku" : "MD03"
}

// ----- SOURCE SCHEMA ----- //
```

Now I want to transform these documents into the following format:

```
// ----- DESIRED FORMAT ----- //

{
    "5564e8dd7c32c85f03ea028c": "MD01",
    "5564e8c97c32c85f03ea028b": "MD02",
    "5564e8dd7c32c85f03ea028c": "MD03"
}

// ----- DESIRED FORMAT ----- //
```

Currently I have to use two `for loop` in server side javascript for this task, but I think it will face performance problems if the collection going bigger.

So how can I archive this by using `only Mongodb queries`? Is the performance of this approach better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Map-Reduce you can achieve the desired output:

```
// map each object to { "XXXXXXXX": sku }
map = function() {
  obj = {}
  obj[this._id.valueOf()] = this.sku
  emit(null, obj)
}

// Aggregate all objects in one (very?) big one
// by copying individual properties
reduce = function(key, values) {
  result = {}
  for (idx in values) {
    for (k in values[idx]) {
      result[k] = values[idx][k]
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Producing:

```
> db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline:1}}).results
[
    {
        "_id" : null,
        "value" : {
            "5564e8937c32c85f03ea028a" : "MD01",
            "5564e8c97c32c85f03ea028b" : "MD02",
            "5564e8dd7c32c85f03ea028c" : "MD03"
        }
    }
]
```

---

**That being said, this is *not* efficient and will eventually hit the 16M limit as you are in fact requesting an aggregation of *all* your DB objects in *one* document only.**